# Ajax form success and fail message not working

Tags: php, ajax, forms

The form on my website is a simple contact form.
I would like the form to show a "success & failed" message on the same page when the form is sent/failed without reloading the page. I understand that I should use Ajax to do this but I can't get it to work. It keeps saying failed but the form is sent and is in my inbox.

Here is the code I'm working with.

Html (single page design):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" class="form" id="contactus" method="post" name="contactus">
  <label for="nametag">Namn*</label> <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value=""> 
  <label for="emailtag">Email*</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value=""> 
  <label for="phonetag">Telefon</label> <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" value=""> 
  <label for="messagetag">Meddelande*</label><br>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" style="width: 87%; height: 200px;"></textarea> 
<label class="placeholder">&nbsp;</label> <button class="submit" name="submit">Skicka</button>
</form>

<script>

        $(function() {
                $('#contactus').submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'php/mail.php',
                        data: $('#contactus').serialize(),
                        success: function(res) {alert(res);
                            if (res == 'successful') {
                                $('#status').html('Sent').slideDown();
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                            } 
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
</script>
```

Php:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
    $subject = "Webbkontakt";
    $formcontent = "Från: $name <br/> Email: $email <br/> Telefon: $phone <br/> Meddelande: $message";

    $headers = "From: " ."<info@mydomain.com>" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". "no-reply@mydomain.com" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

    if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers))
    {
        echo "successful";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the response from the server for the AJAX call?

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but how do I check that? I'm new to this.

Comment: What does `alert(res)` show?

Comment: oh, It shows successful

Comment: @user2566091: Using browser debugging tools you can monitor network requests and responses.  In Firebug, for example, there's a "Net" tab which would show this.

Comment: @David could you take a look at the link up top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the @ symbol in front of mail. Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise. It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination. - in other words, you cannot detect with PHP if the email was sent.

```
if(@mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $headers))
{
    echo "successful";
}else{
   echo "error";
}
```

Then change the success and error to the following in the AJAX:

```
success: function(res) {
    if (res != "successful") { 
        $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown(); 
    } else { 
        $('#status').html('Sent').slideDown(); 
    } 
},

error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert("Error From AJAX"); 
},
```

Comment: I did that now. Could you take a look at the link up top?

Comment: You know your message text-box is in another div outside the form right? Also, you getting error still?

Comment: I moved the text-box and yes I still get the text "failed" on the page but the pop up shows successful. Form appears in my inbox though.

Comment: Try changing your error function in the AJAX so something like this:
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error From AJAX");
    }
This way to can see where the failed error is coming from.

Comment: No change when trying that. :/

Comment: Change success to the following (change it around):

success: function(res) {alert(res);
                        if (res != "successful") {
                         $('#status').html('Failed').slideDown();
                        }
                        else {
$('#status').html('Sent').slideDown();
                        } 
                    },

Comment: Was it that simple. OMG. haha.

Comment: Sent appears now when submitting. Can I make the form empty itself too?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by form empty

Comment: This is what I want. When clicking the submit button the text "sent" appears and the form is reset so that it is clear for the visitor that it has been sent.

Comment: 1. You can set the input values to '' inside the success function, like $('input[name=email]).val() == ''; 2. You'll need to wrap the form tag around both divs if you want it in 2 different divs.

Comment: I fixed #2 so that works now :)   could you show me how to do #1 with my code?

Comment: After $('#status').html('Sent').slideDown(); add the following: document.getElementById("contactus").reset();

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Now it's almost perfect. Thank you so much for spending time helping me. The only thing left for me now is to figure out how to validate all the fields before sending